# Emscripten SDK offline install linux

Tags: emscripten

I was looking into installing Emscripten SDK where I work a couple of weeks ago. The tricky part is that we are not connected to the internet. I cant find any guides for offline installation so I am fishing for some tips on how I should do it. I have two aproatches I will try out which is:

- Download the required zip files manually and change emsdk.py to point to them locally
- Download and install the SDK on a computer with internat acces and then copy the files

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use proxies. EmscriptenSDK dynamically downloads any packages needed, even after installing.

Answer (score 0):

After installing Emscripten, `emsdk` saves the configuration info in `~/.emscripten` and downloads required files to `[EMSDK_HOME]/upstream`. You should be able to install from an internet computer and then copy the required files/folders to the offline computer.